# For loop incremented by variable, time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

```
for (int i = 1; i < a; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j < b; j = j + a){
        Function() <-- O(1)
    }
}
```

In this case, the outer loop will be executed 'a'times(O(a)), and
    the inner loop will be executed 'b/a' times(O(b/a)).

Then the total time complexity will be O(a * b/a ) = O(b)?

I am not this interpretation is right or not..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

Comment: why will the inner loop be executed `b/a` times? You probably mixed a few things up: the loop itself repeats `b` times (`Function()`) and is itself (`for(int j = 1...){...}`) repeated `a` times.

Comment: @Paul I edited the inner loop. Please check it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `O(a * b/a) = O(b)` is obviously right because there is the identity right there: `O(b*a/a) = O(b*1) = O(b)`.

However, it seems like the time complexity is `O(a*b*1)` (assuming looping causes no overheads in time). The computational effort increases linearly with each individual loop size. That is the reason for `O(a*b)`.

Comment: the inner loop has a typo please check it again

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a good question, my thought is

The original complexity should be `O(a) * O(b/a)`

But before you jump into conclusion, you have to judge the cases:

If `b <= a`, then `O(b/a)` = `O(1)`, so `O(a) * O(b/a)` = `O(a)`

If `b > a`, then `O(b/a)` = `O(b/a)`, so `O(a) * O(b/a)` = `O(b)`

So combined these cases, I would say it is `O(max(a,b))`

Answer (score 0):

Armen is correct, the answer is O(ab). We can get the answer by these steps:

O((a-1)(b-1)(1))

=O(ab-a-b+1), which -a-b+1 can be ignored.

=O(ab)

Answer (score 0):

`O(b)` is incorrect since you pass through the outer loop `a` times hence the answer must be at least `O(a)` (and, for all you know, `b` might be much smaller than `a`). The answer should depend on both `a` and `b` rather than `b` alone.

Counting carefully, you pass through the inner loop `ceil((b-1)/a)` times, hence the complexity is

```
O(a*ceil((b-1)/a))
```

But,

```
ceil((b-1)/a) <= (b-1)/a + 1
```

Thus

```
a*ceil((b-1)/a) <= a*((b-1)/a + 1) = b - 1 + a = a + b - 1
```

The 1 is asymptotically negligible, Hence the complexity is `O(a+b)`.

Since `O(a+b) = O(max(a,b))` this agrees with the answer of @shole.